# Markitup picture upload php source code equivalent in asp.net

Tags: php, asp.net, equivalent

I need asp.net equivalent of this source code block.

```
/* The following is a very basic PHP script to handle the upload. One might also
* resize the image (send back the *new* size!) or save some image info to a
* database. Remember that you can modify the widget to include any data you'd like
* submitted along with the uploaded image.
*/ 

$upload_dir = '/var/www/vhosts/test/htdocs/uploads/';

$upload_path = $upload_dir . basename($_FILES['inline_upload_file']['name']);

$response = array();

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['inline_upload_file']['tmp_name'], $upload_path))
{

    $info = getImageSize($upload_path);

    $response['status'] = 'success';
    $response['width'] = $info[0];
    $response['height'] = $info[1];
    $response['src'] = 'http://'
. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
. substr(realpath($upload_path), strlen(realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])));

}
else
{
     $response['status'] = 'error';
     $response['msg'] = $_FILES['inline_upload_file']['error'];
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: I would start by learning ASP.net and doing some actual coding.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway i just googled about php functions and wrote it in asp.net and wanted to add here. It could be helpful for anyone who just want to add image upload plugin for markitup and apply it in asp.net

```
try
{
    string filePath = "/var/www/vhosts/test/htdocs/uploads/";

    if (Request.Files.Count <= 0)
    {
        Response.Write("Please select an image to upload");
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; ++i)
        {
            HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files[i];
            file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(filePath + file.FileName));

            Response.Write("{\"Uploaded FileName\":\"" + file.FileName + "\"}");

            // option to use System.IO fileinfo to get file information
            // FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo.... 
            // option to add an array to return file info + path etc.. 
        } 
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Response.Write("{\"error\": \"" + ex.Message +"\"}");
}
```